# how do I know that the visitors from which traffic source actually does something on my website?

Tags: web

this is a question about traffic analysis tool
let's suppose I have like 20 different traffic sources to my website

then how can I know that visitors from which traffic sources actually are real humans and do somethitng on my website? (browse, scroll down and click buttons and move around inner pages like that)

As we know, we don't have time for testing each traffic source at a time, 
so what I wanna do is that 
buy traffic from 20+ different sources at once and analyse and find out which traffic sources are actually real humans and do something on my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript or etc to download (set no cache flag) a 1x1 pixel image every time an event is triggered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function download() 
{

document.write('<img src="//www.example.com/images/1px.gif?'+Math.random()+'" border="0" height="1" width="1">');


}
</script>
```

then

```
 <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" onclick="download()">
```

Here's a list of events you can trigger on

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

If you name your objects then you can do more.

```
 <a name="user1" href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" onclick="download(this)" onmouseover="download(this)">
```

Now change the definition to download(x) then inside of the download function x.name will be the name of the element that triggered it.

There probably even simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: is there easy solution to do that?

Comment: Thank you for the code, but how do I know which referrer traffic did that behaviour?

Comment: It depends on how the traffic reaches you. Maybe var x = document.referrer;  Then send x in with each request.  Maybe generate a random number, put it in a database, send random number as part of the web page, and track based on that number.  Maybe this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unique_id.html